# How to calculate Session duration and avg. Session duration in Google Analytics raw data?

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

How to calculate Session Duration in Google Analytics raw data which is linked to BigQuery?

I don't know how to calculate session duration in BigQuery!

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide way more information than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the field `totals.timeOnSite` as described in the [ga table schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en), something like:

```
SELECT 
  AVG(totals.timeOnSite) avgTimeOnSite
FROM `project_id.dataset_id.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20170701" and "20170702"
```

Comment: This one can solve my problem! Thanks.
I use this When I count my avg. sessions duration:  <br/>

SELECT 
sum(timeOnpage)/sum(sessions) as avg_sessions

FROM
(SELECT 
  sum(totals.timeOnSite) as timeOnpage,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(fullVisitorId,CAST(visitId AS STRING))) AS sessions
FROM `project_id.dataset_id.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20170702" and "20170703")  <br/>

Answer (score 4):

The following will give you Google Analytics Session duration in Google BigQuery

```
SELECT fullVisitorId, MAX(h.time)/1000 SessionTime
FROM `INSERT_DATASET_NAME.INSERT_TABLE_NAME.ga_sessions_*` , unnest(hits) h 
GROUP BY fullVisitorId
```

and then you can average the results

```
SELECT AVG(sessionTime) AvgSessionTime
FROM 
( 
  SELECT fullVisitorId, MAX(h.time)/1000 sessionTime
  FROM `INSERT_DATASET_NAME.INSERT_TABLE_NAME.ga_sessions_*` , unnest(hits) h 
  GROUP BY fullVisitorId
)
```

You might find the [BigQuery Schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en) useful

Comment: Thank you Daryl ! 
I used Will version that more suitable for me !

Comment: Daryl - ga_sessions_ table is not found

Comment: Why do you divide MAX(h.time) by 1000? is it for simplification purposes or is there some kind of other reason?

Comment: @DinuliThalakumbura as defined in the documentation, the hits.time is: The number of milliseconds after the visitStartTime when this hit was registered. The first hit has a hits.time of 0 (See: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089 ) I voted this solution because you get the avg session duration while  the query is at hit level, with joined hits, which is what you usually need.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Daryl Wenman-Bateson´s answer I did some tests.
It is important to use the right metric for grouping the sessions to get correct data: To count a session you need to ***add the visitId*** to the fullVisitorId to get not the unique users but the session of the unique users:

```
SELECT AVG(sessionTime) avgSessionTime
FROM 
( 
  SELECT
  concat(fullVisitorId, visitId) as sessions,
  MAX(h.time)/1000 as sessionTime
  FROM `INSERT_DATASET_NAME.INSERT_TABLE_NAME.ga_sessions_*` , unnest(hits) h 
  GROUP BY sessions
)
```

I did some **tests** with data from the GA custom reports and with the query above **the numbers match up**.

//Edit:
Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47069527
In my tests I got the same session count as in GA with the statement above, if this does not fit your needs, you can also try CONCAT(fullVisitorId,STRING(visitStartTime)) AS sessionId and totals.visits=1 to match your numbers to be consistent with GA.

Answer (score 0):

The **most reliable way** to calculate avg_session_duration and session_duration that I have found is the following:

```
select
  round(sum(totals.timeonsite/totals.hits), 2) session_duration_sec, 
  round(sum(totals.timeonsite/totals.hits) / count(distinct concat(fullvisitorid, cast(visitstarttime as string))),2) as avg_session_duration_sec, 
from 
    `mhsd-bigquery-project.your_stuff.ga_sessions_*`,
    unnest(hits) as hits
where 
    (_table_suffix BETWEEN
    FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 Day))
    AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 Day)))
    -- choose whatever time span you like
    ;
```

NOTE that it is **important** to devide the sum of timeonsite by the number of hits since this query unnests hits!!!
I find this is something the other answers lack.