# DIfference between Bigquery and GA in sessions per Landing content grouping

Tags: sql, session, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I want to use Bigquery to report on the number of sessions per landing content group per source / medium. Basically I want to reproduce the GA report: Behaviour - Site content - Landing Pages - Select content group - Select custom dimension Source / Medium.

Bigquery reports more sessions (around 1% - 2%) as GA. Is there something wrong with this query? (No sampling in GA)

```
SELECT
  date,
  Landing_Content_Group,
  Source_Medium,
  COUNT(1) AS Sessions
FROM (
  SELECT
    date,
    CONCAT(fullVisitorId,STRING(visitId)) AS sessionId,
    hits.contentGroup.contentGroup1 AS Landing_Content_Group,
    trafficSource.source +'/'+ trafficSource.medium AS Source_Medium
  FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([TABLE], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -3, 'DAY'), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -3, 'DAY')))
  WHERE
    hits.hitnumber = 1
  GROUP BY
    date,
    sessionId,
    Landing_Content_Group,
    Source_Medium )
GROUP BY
  date,
  Landing_Content_Group,
  Source_Medium
ORDER BY Sessions DESC
```

Comment: I wonder what happens if you add: `WHERE hits.hitNumber = 1 AND totals.visits = 1`. Does it work?

Comment: It gets me to less session but still a higher number compared to GA. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

`CONCAT(fullVisitorId,STRING(visitId)) AS sessionId` is good to count sessions without midnight split. `visitId` stays the same over the split.

Use `CONCAT(fullVisitorId,STRING(visitStartTime)) AS sessionId` and `totals.visits=1` (=sessions with any interaction) to be consistent with GA.