# Calculate Session Length from Google Analytics data in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, duration

How do you calculate session length for website event data that flows via Google Analytics to BigQuery ?

A similar question has been posted & answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45077970/how-to-calculate-session-duration-and-avg-session-duration-in-google-analytics). However, the underlying data structure is very different to my case:

- Our data structure is: `project_id.dataset_id.events_*` with a separate table for each day, instead of `project_id.dataset_id.ga_sessions_*`

The way I've tried to get the session length is with the `user_engagement` event and the `engagement_time_msec` field:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'ga_session_id') AS session_id,
  SUM((SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'engagement_time_msec'))/60.0 as session_length_seconds
FROM `project_id.dataset_id.events_*`
WHERE event_name = 'user_engagement'
GROUP BY 1
```

But I'm getting NULL values for some sessions: [BigQuery Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6Nxf.png)

I haven't found good documentation from Google on this, so any help or links would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [article](https://www.meliorum.com.au/blog/the-ga4-update-matching-big-query-data-with-google-analytics) explains very well how to calculate session length:

Basically there are two ways:

- Engaged Session Length (using maximum `engagement_time_msec`) which seems to indicate that `engagement_time_msec` is a cumulative metrics
- Normal Session Length (using the difference of the maximum & minimum `event_timestamp` across all events)

Pasting the section of the article here:

> **Average Session Duration** Again this has changed slightly to engaged session duration. This will be lower than your Universal
> Analytics session duration as it only counts when the tab is in focus.
> Below I show how to do both.

```sql
SELECT
  sum(engagement_time_msec)/1000 #in milliseconds
  /count(distinct concat(user_pseudo_id,ga_session_id)) as ga4_session_duration,
  sum(end_time-start_time)/1000000 #timestamp in microseconds
  /count(distinct concat(user_pseudo_id,ga_session_id)) as ua_session_duration

from(
  SELECT
    user_pseudo_id,
    (select value.int_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'ga_session_id') as ga_session_id,
   max((select value.int_value from unnest(event_params) where key = 'engagement_time_msec')) as engagement_time_msec,
   min(event_timestamp) as start_time,
   max(event_timestamp) as end_time
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.ga4_obfuscated_sample_ecommerce.events_*`
  where _table_suffix BETWEEN "20210101" and "20210131"
  group by 1,2)
```